# How to Store Data in Android Application

Tags: java, android, store

I have some codes here that user can set a value using `EditText` in my layout. When user set number in text input and  clicks on "set" button, value of EditText input, transmitted to a `TextView`. This is some image of that.
[image]

Here is my XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textview" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:id="@+id/set" />
```

And java codes:

```
textview= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
edittext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
set = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.set);

set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Now I want to keep value of "textview" after restarting app or device, it's matter to save all my data in internal storage.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving of that kind of the information for you is  quite nice to use `SharedPreferences`. This is quite easy and fast way to manage data.

*To write :*

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("fristRow",userid.getText().toString());
editor.putString("secondRow",password.getText().toString());
editor.apply();
```

*To Read :*

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String Astatus = preferences.getString("fristRow", "");
```

Comment: I'm using fragment activity and can't use "getSharedPreferences"

Comment: // this = your fragment SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: What about "getString"?

Comment: The same as in the example preferences.getString("fristRow", "");

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store simple data like that. If you need to save bigger amounts, use a database.

Comment: Can you tell me more with some codes? sorry but I'm new in android

Comment: check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: @MohammadFarahi If you're new to android, you should be reading the documentation. Believe or not, but I'm new to android as well, and yesterday was the first time I ever used `SharedPreferences`. Did you know how I knew to use it? I googled, and probably got a stackoverflow answer as a result.

Answer (score 1):

first Sqlite databse

Senad SharedPreferences

Third internet storage(SdCarc)

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences and for further help take  look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link if you need to know more about SharedPreferences Helper Class

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` for this purpose

```
set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                        Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                        prefsEditor.putString("text_value", edittext.getText().toString());
                        prefsEditor.commit();
                    }
                });
```

Inorder to read the value

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String textValue = prefs.getString("text_value", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

To store some simple data, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PRE_NAME, 0);//get the preference object
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
  editor.putString("key_here", value_here);//store some value(key-->value)
  editor.commit();//commit the changes
```

and you can use sp.getXXXX() to get the data stored:

```
   SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   String storedValue = sp.getString("your_key", default_value);
```

If you want some data stored in structure, you can use SQL Lite.

Please refer to [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for more details.